# Google Scripts API - autoUpdateForwarding Not Applying

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, urlfetch

As Domain Admin for the company I work at we'd like to set the forwarding addresses of staff as they leave the company to ensure any important correspondence isn't missed.

I've used the Google Apps OAuth2 Library successfully so far, but come across a snag. The following code is meant to forward emails from the address **apitest@example.com** to **newaddress@example.com** .

```
function setupForwarding() {
  var service = getOAuthService();
  service.reset();
  try {
    if (service.hasAccess()) {
      var header = {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken(),
      }
      var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/apitest@example.com/settings/autoForwarding";
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        headers: header,
        method: 'put',
        enabled: true,
        emailAddress: 'newaddress@example.com',
        disposition: 'trash'
      });
      Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    }
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.message);
  }
}
```

The access token provided appears to work with other queries provided by UrlFetchApp such as using it to return the currently authorised forwarding addresses recorded on the account (which does include newaddress@example.com) and doesn't report any access priviledge errors. The response returns only the following

```
{ "enabled" : false }
```

And does not apply any forwarding. Would someone be able to help me identify the problem? I feel I might be passing the parameters to the HTTP request incorrectly but I'm still learning my way around that system and no other questions I found seemed to help.

- Ozzie

Comment: Is this being done from the service account? Per the REST API documentation for [`Gmail.Users.settings.updateAutoForwarding`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/updateAutoForwarding) the executing user must be a service account with domain-wide authority.

Comment: The service account running it does have domain-wide authority which seems to be working for other requests; just this one i'm struggling with.

Comment: You could try enabling the Advanced Service for Gmail in the project, and then using the native client library, i.e. `Gmail.Users....`

Answer (score 2):

I worked this out and it was simpler than I thought; so sharing the answer here in case anyone has a similar issue.

```
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: header,
      method: 'put',
      contentType : 'application/json',
      payload: '{ "enabled" : "true" , "emailAddress" : "newaddress@example.com" , "disposition" : "trash" }'
    });
```

Is the functional way to do this; the request was expecting a separate payload and declared content type both.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer Ozzie. I wasted hours on the same problem. It's sad that Google Gmail API isn't clear on the separate "payload" structure in their documentation. I put the "enabled" and "emailAddress", and "disposition" fields in the response body as you did.